# Laravel migration error on creating table with foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using laravel's artisan command to create a database table with a foreign key. I'm getting the following error when I run the `php artisan migrate` command:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1022 Can't write;
>   duplicate key in table '#sql-73_ca' (SQL: alter table `table_1` add
>   constraint `table_1_table_1_sid_foreign` foreign key
>   (`table_1_sid`) references `table_2` (`id`))

Also, I don't have a table '#sql-73_ca'

Comment: share  your migration snippets .

Comment: Could you please post the code of all relevant migrations?

Comment: can you plz share your both table migrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you using phpmyadmin you should copy a section of error notification to the query sql in phpmyadmin:

```
" alter table table_1 add constraint table_1_table_1_sid_foreign 
foreign key (table_1_sid) references table_2 (id)"
```

It will display more information for error

Answer (score 0):

Its about unique() command in your migration file. 
You should delete this if you dont wanna get error. 
Or add a function for if there is unique column. 
You should share your migration. We cant understand with this.

Also you can try this in related controller.

```
 try { //codes
} catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e){
            $errorCode = $e->errorInfo[1];
            if($errorCode == '1062'){
                echo('Error Message');
            }
        }
```